# How do you substitute into symbolic gradient in sympy module?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I use the code

```
from sympy.physics.vector import *
RF = ReferenceFrame('e')
from sympy.physics.vector import gradient
scalar_field = 1/(sqrt(RF[0]**2+RF[1]**2+RF[2]**2))
gradient(scalar_field, RF)
```

The output is

[image]

Now I want to make substitutions, e_x = 1, etc., or maybe e_x= t.
Does it possible? How?

Comment: e_x is a vector, so I am not sure to understand what you want. Can you expand a bit on your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitutions are performed with [`subs` method](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.subs), for example:

```
gr = gradient(scalar_field, RF)
gr.subs({RF[0]: 1, RF[1]: 2, RF[2]: 3})
```

outputs

```
- sqrt(14)/196*e.x - sqrt(14)/98*e.y - 3*sqrt(14)/196*e.z
```

You can also substitute formulas, say

```
var('t')
gr.subs({RF[0]: 1, RF[1]: t, RF[2]: 3*t+2})
```